# Zeit/Now deployment stopped working. No errors are shown

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter, twitter-oauth, vercel

I have made a Twitter bot that is deployed on now.sh

The bot was working fine for few hours and then it stuck!

It was expected to **Tweet an Everyday Trend (Everyday)** as it does before. Before, it was also **streaming after new followers to send them a ThankU message**. *Now, all that just stopped.*

I'm using the code, hosted on [this GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/glitter).

**This is the screenshot of stagnant logs at now.sh**

[image: The screenshot of how bot is not working after...]

The same code is working as expected for 24 hours locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently focusing on hosting HTTP/WebSocket servers, so every deployment is frozen when they don't receive an HTTP request for a while. You can read more about it here: https://zeit.co/docs/guides/app-lifecycle-and-scalability#instances-&-scaling

For example, if you want to ensure that your deployment will **always** have one running instance in our `sfo` region (regardless of incoming traffic), you can run `now scale deployment.now.sh sfo 1`.